# Как работать с функциями в языке Си?

Tags: c, функции

Компилируется,но ответ не выводится((
Отдельно работала каждая.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define MAX_SIZE 10

int even_elements(int, int, int);
int second(int, int, int);
int palindrome(int, int, int);
int sort(int, int, int);

int main()
{
    int size_array , res, i, arr[10];
    printf("How many number you want to enter ?\n");
    res=scanf("%d", &size_array);
    if( size_array == 0 || size_array == 1 || size_array > 10 || res!=1 )
        printf("Not right size of array");
    else
    {
        printf("Enter %d Numbers :", size_array);
        for (i = 0; i < size_array; i++)
            scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}

int even_elements(int size_array,int res, int i)
{
    int arr[MAX_SIZE], e=0;
    if(size_array<11)
    {
        printf("Enter %d elements in the array: ", size_array);
        for(i=0; i<size_array; i++)
        {
            if(arr[i]%2==0)
                e = e +arr[i];   
        }
        printf("Sum of even elements of array = %d", e);
    }
    else
    puts("Not right size of array");

    return 0;
}

int second(int size_array,int res, int i)
{
    int sum = 0, size=0, arr[50], b[50];
    for (i = 0; i < size_array; i++)
            sum = sum + arr[i];

    int average = sum / size_array;
    for (i = 0; i < size_array; i++)
        if (arr[i] > average)
        {
            b[size] = arr[i];
            size++;
        }

    printf("New array: ");
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
        printf("%d ", b[i]);
    return 0;
}

int palindrome(int size_array,int res, int i)
{
   int reverse = 0, temp;
   temp = size_array;
   while( temp != 0 )
   {
      reverse = reverse * 10;
      reverse = reverse + temp%10;
      temp = temp/10;
   }
   if ( size_array == reverse )
      printf("%d is a palindrome number.\n", size_array);
   else
      printf("%d is not a palindrome number.\n", size_array);
   return 0;
}

int sort(int size_array,int res, int i) 
{
    int a[50], j, temp = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < size_array; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &a[i]);
    }

        printf("The given array is:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < size_array; i++)
        printf("%d ", a[i]);    
    for (i = 0; i < size_array; i++)
    {
        for (j = i + 1; j < size_array; j++)
        {
            if (a[i] > a[j])
            {
                temp = a[i];
                a[i] = a[j];
                a[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }       
        printf("\nThe sorted array using Buble sort is:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < size_array; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ", a[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: си не умеет вызывать функции "телепатически". В main Вы просто вводите массив, но больше ничего с ним не делаете. То есть,нужно дописать код вызова нужных функций *явно*. А вот каких и в какой последовательности - это Вам виднее.

Comment: В этом то и заключается вопрос, не получается сделать чтобы нормально передавать значения в **main**. Хотел увидеть рабочую версию . @KoVadim

Comment: @Systemlog64, я так понимаю, вы хотите ввести массив и применить к нему поочередно все эти функции?

Comment: @eanmos Да кроме функции палиндром, она работает уже нормально и вообще не связанна с массивами.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В функции `main` вы создаете массив и заполняете его какими-то числами. Теперь вам нужно произвести некоторые действия с этим массивом:

1. Вывести сумму четных элементов (`even_elements`);
2. Отсортировать (`sort`);
3. Вывести все числа, которые больше среднего значения (`second`).

#### 1. `even_elements`

Вам нужно вывести все четные элементы массива, созданного в функции `main`. Но вы (зачем-то) создаете **новый** массив и не инициализируете его (т. е. получается так, что он содержит случайные значения).

Так что все, что нам нужно сделать — это передать массив из `main` в нашу функцию:

```
int even_elements(int* arr, int size_array, int res, int i) {
    int e = 0;
    ...
}
```

#### 2. `sort`

То же, что и в предыдущем пункте — вы не передаете в функцию массив из `main` и снова создаете новый. Исправляем:

```
int sort(int* a, int size_array, int res, int i)  {
    int j, temp = 0;
    ...
}
```

Нам потребовалось удалить первый цикл и вот эту вот `a[50],` штуку :).

#### 3. `second`

Тут мне вас точно не чем удивить — передаем массив через аргументы:

```
int second(int* arr, int size_array, int res, int i) {
    int sum = 0, size = 0, b[50];
```

---

Все функции вызываются одинаково:

```
even_elements(arr, size_array, 0, 0);
sort(arr, size_array, 0, 0);
second(arr, size_array, 0, 0);
```

Думаю, вам стоит убрать из аргументов `res` (вообще не используется) и `i` (счетчик можно объявить в цикле).